# Mobile number verification in order checkout - Magento framework

Tags: magento, mobile, numbers, verification

i done eCommerce website using "Magento" framework, we provide product services only in India.
am very newbie for magento framework. We want to implement a modules for mobile number verification in order checkout. if mobile number is valid, order should be processed. we have indian sms gateway api. any modules or extensions available ?

Comment: This one is perfect solution https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a free one..

This is premium:

http://www.zypo.com/final-sms-pro-for-magento

But you can always pay someone..

Comment: Thanks John,  but "Final SMS Pro for Magento" extension can verify mobile number in registration page only. we want verify mobile number in before order placed. want to verify shipment number what ever user gave. is that option available ?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution "comment by xavier" in stack overflow itself . A new way of mobile number verification with no fee

[Mobile Phone no. verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660692/mobile-phone-no-verification/28192688#28192688)